# Android Null Pointer Exception when sending latitude and longitude to database

Tags: php, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am making and simple android app to store latitude and longitude mysql database.I have create an local database.databse has 3 fields id which is auto incremented and two fields lat2(float) and lng2(float) to store values from android.

Here is my logcat error

```
  12-28 16:45:04.470: D/gralloc_goldfish(1400): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-28 16:45:11.190: D/AndroidRuntime(1400): Shutting down VM
12-28 16:45:11.190: W/dalvikvm(1400): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a71ba8)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): Process: com.example.test, PID: 1400
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-28 16:45:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 16:45:17.380: I/Process(1400): Sending signal. PID: 1400 SIG: 9
```

Here is my main activity

```
    package com.example.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private float lat;
    private float lng;
    private String lat2;
    private String lng2;
    MainActivity gps;
    private String line;
    Button btninsert;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


          btninsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
          btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){   
                     lat = (float) gps.getLatitude();
                     lng = (float) gps.getLongitude();
                     lat2= String.valueOf(lat);
                     lng2= String.valueOf(lng);




        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success insert - \nLat: " + lat2 + "\nLong: " + lng2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
                }});
        }


        protected void showSettingsAlert() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


        protected float getLatitude() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
        protected float getLongitude() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }


        protected boolean canGetLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


        public void insert(String result, String lat2,String lng2) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat2", lat2));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng2", lng2));

            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.31/insert_android.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }

            try {
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                lng2 = (json_data.getString("code"));

                if (lng2 == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
            }
        }

}
```

Here is my php Script

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$conn =  mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Blah');

if ($conn) {

mysql_select_db("test", $conn);

// extract your data
if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng']) ){


$lat2 = $_POST['lat'];
$lng2 = $_POST['lng'];



        $query2 = "INSERT INTO markers_awal VALUES('','$lat2','$lng2')";

    if (mysql_query($query2, $conn))
    echo "data inserted";
    else {
        echo "Oh dear " . mysql_error();


    }
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: which is line number 44 in MainActivity?

Comment: Your code is really mess and incorrect. Where is setContentview() ?? Set your activity first.

Comment: @Keshav1234  line 44 is  -     insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: And you shouldn't connect to the server from the main thread. Run it in background. `findViewById` during `onCreate`?

Comment: @frz3993 i didnt get what u asked?

Comment: your insert method is completely wrong .Why are you passing parameter in it when you are not even using it??

Comment: @VivekMishra what kind of method u supposed to me do this task?just i want to store lat and long in my mysql database

Comment: if you want to add it through method then pass both parameters in mehtod and don't use global lat long in your insert mehtod.
Your method should look something like this
public void insert(String latitude,String longitude){
..
}
and then add them in your arraylist

Comment: @VivekMishra i have updat the code please have a look?

Comment: now you are not calling insert method anywhere

Comment: and also change your variable name they might cause issue as in which you are getting value and those you are passing as parameter are same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, you have an object called `gps` which is of `MainActivity` that is actually the same activity you're in.

So two problems,

- You don't need that `gps` object at all. just call `canGetLocation` without `gps.canGetLocation`.
- Secondly, if you really want to keep that weird `gps` object then you have to assigned a value to it, which would be `gps = this;` in your case.

That would surely solve your `NullPointerException`

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for the intrusion ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK np. Thanks for that.

Comment: i have checked the id and it is correct.still i am getting that error

Comment: @colombo set ContentView first. Debug the code and then check whether that id is null or not.

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo i have set the content view but still i have log cat errors.I have update my log cat errors.

Comment: @colombo I don't see setContentView call in your activity above. Update your activity code again.

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo Sorry...i just have update my activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99085/discussion-between-jabbar-jigariyo-and-colombo).

Comment: @jabbar_jigariyo now i got to run the application.but when i click the send button it stops the application.with some log cat errors.

Comment: @colombo What are tho se new errors ? It can't be same error right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99101/discussion-between-colombo-and-jabbar-jigariyo).

Comment: I have added updated my log cat errors and Main Activity.plz check.this time when i am click the send button it stops the application.

Comment: @colombo I got your problem, and have updated the answer. This was an inappropriate  post. Please do use `review stackoverflow` page rather than posting this type of question here.

Comment: @jabbar_jigariyo Thank you very much.i have solve that.i am new to the android and stackoverflow.thank u

Comment: can somebody helped me i cant pass lat and long to mysql database.there are no errors in program.

Answer (score 1):

your are using gps class, so where you initialize gps? 
if you not initialize gps then initialize it. and I also observe that there in no super constructor in your code before setContentView method. put this into your code.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: please check lat and long is not null.

Comment: @colombo, There is no super constructor in your onCreate() method & where is GPS implementation code

Answer (score 0):

to convert your float values into `String` use method

```
String lat2 = String.valueOf(lat);
String lng2 = String.valueOf(lng);
```

and please make sure these value are having some value. Check using Log or toast message.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting an error at line number 51. Which is actually your onclick method. Can you check you ***canGetLocation()*** method each time its returning a false value. and also you are getting a null pointer exception, according to you logcat. put your all data inside the onclick method into the try catch block.